# Group Indicators in android.widget.ExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, expandablelistview

I have to populate an ExpandableListView in my application. ExpandableListView consists of a set of groups which in turn consists of a set of children.

For e.g.

**   **Group1**

```
...ChildA

...ChildB
```

**Group2**

```
...ChildC
...ChildD
```

.
   .
   .

**GroupN**

```
...ChildM1
...ChildM2**
```

By default the Groups have an arrow indicator to the left. I wanted to change that arrow indicator to an image icon. I want to set a different image icon for each group. 
For example,

Group1 will have a tree icon.
Group2 will have an animal icon and so on.

Is it also possible to have a different icon indicator for each child in each group ?
If yes i would be glad to have some guidance on that too.

I have tried many approaches but haven't been successful. Is it something to do with the emulator support as i am running my application on the emulator.

Looking forward to your help.

Thanks,
Adithya.

Answer (score 14):

Use `android:groupIndicator` like,

```
<ExpandableListView ...
    android:groupIndicator="@drawable/group_indicator" >
```

**group_indicator.xml** can be a selector to show a different arrow(state) if the item is expanded or collapsed:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_empty="true" android:drawable="@drawable/collapsed_drawable" />
    <item android:state_expanded="true" android:drawable="@drawable/expanded_drawable" />

</selector>
```

**Or in code** like,

```
expandableView.setGroupIndicator(context.getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.group_indicator));
```

Hope, this will help you.

Comment: Please add comments while down voting the answer. This will give a clue for correction. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Disable the group indicator in the ExpandableListView you are using then change your group and child row layouts to include an ImageView at the start of the row. In your adapter for the ExpandableListView add logic to choose an appropriate icon to display in the ImageView.

Their is an example of this [here](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2011/06/hiding-group-indicator-for-empty-groups.html). The example shows how to hide the expand/collapse icon for empty groups. The idea is the same for custom group/child icons, but obviously your logic will be different.

Answer (score 0):

android:groupIndicator="@drawable/roundbackground"

Check this and if you want to move the indicator then check this

http://androidcodesnips.blogspot.com/2011/07/expandable-list-view-move-group-icon.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+Androidcodes+%28AndroidCodes%29

there you found moving the indicator position and example of constructing a expandable list

Comment: i don't want to re - position the indicator. I want to change the arrow icon to something else for each group indicator so that wach group indicator has a different image icon.

Comment: Then use this line in the xml file      android:groupIndicator="@drawable/roundbackground"

Comment: i want to do it logically..lets say i am displaying animal groups..carnivores,herbivores,omnivores,etc..so i want to display a lion icon for carnivore group indicator, deer icon for herbivore group indicator and human icon for omnivores group indicator..That's the reason i don't want to hard code it.

Answer (score -3):

I think this isn't supported by Android yet ! :)